# how i can show my own active class on items in owl slider by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, owl-carousel

How can I show my own active class on items in owl slider by click.. my active class added but slider does not move to 6th child.. why is that?

```
<div    class="all_series">      
          <div class="owl-carousel">          
            <div class="item"> slider1 </div>
             <div class="item"> slider2 </div>
              <div class="item"> slider3 </div>
               <div class="item"> slider4 </div>    
</div>  </div>

<script>        
    $(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".owl-item.active")        .removeClass("active");    
    $(".owl-item:nth-child(6)")  .addClass("active ");

});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.myactive {

background-color: #ff9704;
```

}

I got the answer of my question..

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".owl-item:nth-child(6)")  .addClass("myactive "); 
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', 6 );

});

Answer (score 1):

Did you called the plugin? You need to do that first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

To go to a specified element you need to call

```
$(".owl-carousel").trigger('to.owl.carousel', index);
```

where index is the nth element of the carousel. If you call it when page is ready, than you specify a "default" element.